# Stop babel parse and generate reformatting output code

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using @babel/parser to read in javascript, modify it and regenerate it with babel-generator. I need to do this while retaining the javascript's formatting but it's re-formatting it. I can't see anything else in the options for the parser or generator or docs that would stop it from doing this so I'm a bit lost. Here's what I have so far.

```
import { parse } from '@babel/parser';
import generate from 'babel-generator';

var file = parse(script, {
    sourceType: 'module',
    ranges: true,
    tokens: true,
    plugins: ['nullishCoalescingOperator', 'typescript']
});

var script = generate(file, {
    retainLines: true,
    comments: true
});
console.log(script.code);
```

The test script I am passing it is below;

```
import This from 'that'
import That from './this'

export default (() => {
    return Object.assign(
        {},
        This
        {
            That
        }
    )
})()
```

However generate is returning the script below;

```
import This from 'that'
import That from './this'

export default (() => {
  return Object.assign(
  {},
  This
  {
    That });


})();
```

As you can see it's changing the number of spaces in a return, collapsing the end }) of the Object.assign and adding semi-colons. It will be reading in script from lots of different formats and styles and I can't change it and ideally don't want to have to provide it with an es-lint file, is there anyway to get it to print the code back out with the exact same formatting?

EDIT: the ast nodes contain the loc and range vales but it seems to be ignoring it. I'm not even sure if it's parsing it incorrectly or if the generate is ignoring it.

```
"loc": {
    "start": {
        "line": 10,
        "column": 8
    },
    "end": {
        "line": 10,
        "column": 10
    }
},
"range": [
    319,
    321
],
```

Comment: did you tried all of the options here https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-generator#options

Comment: @canbax "I can't see anything else in the options for the parser or generator or docs that would stop it from doing this so I'm a bit lost"

Comment: just try all of them one by one. One of them might be responsible for this.

Comment: @canbax I have, none of them really make sense to allow/disable reformatting on the output, I'm looking into how generate recreates the tree but it's like pulling teeth

Comment: did you try writing the string to file? maybe console.log will print in a specific format?

Answer (score 0):

you need use jscodeshift, instead of babel.This library is more suitable for this scenario.
https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift